# Odd Behavior on Image Size in HTTPS

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, uri

I have been learning HTML and CSS and i am creating a WebSite there is a section where I add 3 images, and this images have an odd behavior when displaying.

when I access to the website on Samsung Internet under HTTP i get them as expected: [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaLnG.jpg)

but when I access under HTTPS i get: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw13q.jpg)

I have notice that it works under HTTP and HTTPS on other browsers like chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is an instance of mixed content that occurs when HTML pages load over an HTTPS connection but link to resources (images, CSS, or JS) over an insecure HTTP connection. This is generally triggered by inputting an image within the page that runs over an HTTP connection. When you upload and post images but do not update the image links on the page after getting an SSL certification, the browsers will recognize them as insecure elements.

For your own domain, serve all content as HTTPS and fix your links. Often, the HTTPS version of the content already exists, and this just requires adding an “s” to links – http:// to https://.
For images hosted on other domains, use the site’s HTTPS version if available.

[sitechecker](https://sitechecker.pro/site-audit-issues/https-page-links-http-image/)